# SignalR and one browser window for a session at a time

Tags: concurrency, browser, signalr, optimistic-concurrency

I have a situation where a user can modify an Excel like grid schedule online.  I would like to be able to show a message stating that the schedule is being modified in another window.  However, how can I do this with a window open, and if the previous window was closed with SignalR.  For other sessions I just want to state another user is modifying the schedule.

Comment: Pretty vague what exactly you are asking. Can you provide a simple scenario?

Comment: View schedule page, open tab and navigate to same schedule page, but show message the schedule page is already being viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to use localStorage to communicate between multiple tabs/windows a single user has open: http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/

You can listen for the [storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event which is triggered on every window a user has open on your site when you call `localStorage.setItem` or `localStorage.removeItem`.

Of course, it would still make sense to use SignalR to notify other users.

If you cannot use the localStorage API for some reason, you can still use SignalR to send a message to every window the user has open by using `Clients.User(userName)....` inside your Hub. By default, `userName` should match your user's `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`, but you can register your own `IUserIdProvider` to customize this: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider